# How to Check given string is in HTML format or not in swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, regex, swift5

In one scenario I need to check whether api response is in HTML format or in JSON format. For that first I am converting data to string and checking is it in HTML format or not?. Is there  any Regex available to check string is html string or not? or is there any another way available?.

Comment: Check if the very first non-whitespace character is a `<` => HTML or not => JSON. Apart from that API response normally send headers along detailing what the response is: [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)

Answer (score 5):

Check a string is a HTML string:

```
func isValidHtmlString(_ value: String) -> Bool {
    if value.isEmpty {
        return false
    }
    return (value.range(of: "<(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">])*>", options: .regularExpression) != nil)
}

let testString = "<p> test html string </p>"
print("\(isValidHtmlString(testString))")
```

Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-validate-html-tag-using-regular-expression/

Check a string is a JSON string:

```
let jsonString = "{}"
if JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!) {
        print("valid")
} else {
        print("invalid")
}
```